# chapter headings change alignment to center and without the word "chapter"

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want chapter heading as `1. chapter_name` and `center` aligned. How can I get this? I have searched the net for an answer but I am able to get only separate answers but not combined answer for the both requirements. Please help and thank you in advance...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

With `book` or `report` class, using `titlesec` package, here is an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}
{\thechapter.}
{10pt}
{\Huge}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}
{}
{0pt}
{\Huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{20pt}    %% adjust these as you like
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{20pt}{20pt}  %% adjust these as you like

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Un-numbered chapter

[image]

Numbered chapter

[image]

Comment: @adibro You are welcome. Please remember that you can also accept answers that helped you solve the problem. Please see [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) for details. :-)